# Norm of Laplacian of a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, laplacian

Let $M$ be a closed Riemannian manifold and $\beta$ be a $p$-form on $M$. So, the Hodge-Laplacian $\Delta\beta$ is again a $p$-form. I want to know if we have any relation or inequality regarding $\Delta|\beta|^2$ and $\Delta\beta$.

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta \beta$ rather than $\nabla \beta$?

Comment: @Didier opps, yes. Fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition** (Bochner-weitzenbock formula). For any $p$-form $\beta$,
$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta|\beta|^2=|\nabla \beta|^2-\langle\Delta \beta,\beta\rangle+F(\beta),$$
where $F$ is a complicate expression related to curvature tensor.

For proof and more information see

*Poor, Walter A.*, Differential geometric structures, New York etc.: McGraw-Hill Book Company. XIII, 338 p. DM 102.13 (1981). [ZBL0493.53027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0493.53027).

and

*Petersen, Peter*, Riemannian geometry, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 171. New York, NY: Springer. xvi, 432 p. (1998). [ZBL0914.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0914.53001).